Alexander duality, Hatcher

Hi, I’m studying hatcher book and I’m bit confused with the proof of Alexander duality for hypersphere. The start and the conclusion are ok, but I can’t see why there’s a corresponding sequence with a point which makes this one splits. I tried thinking about excision since locally contractible, or about the naturality of long exact sequence … maybe I’m missing some previous results or it’s easier than I think, thank you for any help

Please, when you cite a book, give its title... not only the name of its author...

@JeanMarie Usage of "Hatcher" like this is universally understood to refer to his book "Algebraic Topology." There's no need to clarify in this specific instance.

@Ben Steffan Sorry to be so stupid... But recognize that my advise can be useful in other cases...

$K$ is (locally) contractible to any point of $K$.  $K$ is a "big", closed set, but homologically, deleting it modifies the sphere only as much deleting a point does.  (The same idea in 2-d: the open annulus is isotopic to a punctured disk -- because the "inner, missing disk of the annulus" is closed and contractible to a point, the point we would delete from the disk.  Don't try to carry this argument down to 1-d without thinking carefully.)

@EricTowers any reference for this? Usually hatcher uses easy arguments, I can’t see why omitted it

This is an easy argument.  Maybe think through why $S^2$ minus a connected, compact set is isotopic to a disk (a once punctured $S^2$).
